# Global Variables in Pytest conftest.py

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I had a working test project where I loaded the data in `conftest.py` and was able to use that data in all my tests in that directory. For some reason, it's stopped working.

`conftest.py`:

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
   global test_data
   test_data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=None, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

`test_temp1.py`:

```py
from conftest import *
def input_data():
    print(test_data)
```

```
Error:
E   NameError: name 'test_data' is not defined
```

I have tried declaring the variables outside `pytest_configure()`, but the value initalized in `pytest_configure` has scope only inside the function. Not sure if there were any recent updates that could have caused this. Any idea or suggestion on a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the change comes from this [deprecation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-config-global).
You can define kind of global variables in the [pytest's namespace](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace).

```py
## conftest.py

def pytest_configure(config):
   pytest.test_data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=None, sheet_name='Sheet1')

## test file

from pytest import test_data

def test_input_data():
   print(test_data)
```

### Notes: use of fixtures

If you can perform some refactoring, the way to deal with data that are loaded in Pytest is called [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html).
So you could define your test data as a fixture and use (request it) in your tests.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def test_data():
   return pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=None, sheet_name='Sheet1')

def test_input_data(test_data):
   print(test_data)
```

You can even choose the scope of the fixture to perform this data loading according to your needs, see [fixture scopes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes).

Comment: Is there way to make the data loaded in conftest global. Because, I was actually loading a lot of data using conftest and then using it in the actual test script to determine the actual inputs for the tests. what I was doing earlier was conftest > Test Script function that creates the actual inputs for tests > tests

Comment: @RajeshS got it. I've made another proposal that should better suit your needs. Tell me.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, only change was that we dont have to explicitly do from pytest import test_data, it would complain there is no attribute test_data. Just import pytest works